# How to get optional parameters in mvc action C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is an TestAction in HomeController as below:

```
    public ActionResult TestAction(string a = "a", int b = 2, int c = 1)
    {
        var DATA = Request.Params;//Can't get param neither a nor b
        return View();
    }
```

If my visit link is "/Home/TestAction?c=23". Then DATA will be {c=23}, but not contain a and b. 
Does there any way to get these two params to make DATA like {a="a", b=2, c=23} by visit link "/Home/TestAction?c=23". (These params are different in different page, so can't hard-code).

Comment: Unclear what your asking - if the `url is `Home/TestAction` then the value of `a` is "a" and `b` is 2. If the url is `Home/TestAction?a=xyz&b=5`, then the values of `a` and `b` will be "xyz" and 5 respectively.

Comment: What do you need to have in DATA? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. "Request.Params" are not get filled with the default values in the method. If you send params in the URL it will appear in Request.Params. @Html.ActionLink("click1", "Test", new {a = "e", b = 22, c = 23}) will give you all a,b and c in the querystring where 
@Html.ActionLink("click2", "Test", new {c = 23 }) will only have c.

Comment: I need all three params even I didn't pass value by the link. Because I think they were mentioned by optional params.

Comment: @SheldonLou, Sorry, but this is nonsense You already have all 3 values (they are the values of the 3 parameters in the method) What are you trying to do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need this value pairs to build a pagination component for our project. Now, I did this by passing these two value at first time, then it will be exist all pages.

Comment: The web is stateless. Every time you make a new request, its initializes a new instance of your controller. Unless you persist the values, the they are lost. And there is nothing in your question about pagination or how you are implementing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by passing the params in the url as following. The model binder will read the query string and pass these parameter values to the action method.

```
/Home/TestAction?a=valuea&b=valueb
```

You can also use the route data to pass the value. An appropriate route will need to be defined to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Take all the paramters as nullable
**int?,
string** accepts null by default.
So after changes your method will look like

```
public ActionResult TestAction(string a, int? b, int? c)
{
   //Check conditions for null here
    return View();
}
```